# Android, how to know the lastest version of specific sdk version of library like appcompat

Tags: android, android-studio

For example,for some reasons I need to degrade API 24 to API 23,

so the appcompat version also need to be changed,now is 24.1.1,

but how can I know the latest version of API 23 ? 
23.?.?

Comment: Also, for build tools:https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/build-tools.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The revision history is documented at [Support Library Revision History](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html).  You have to scroll around if you want to go to much older versions, but they are reasonably good about keeping this page up to date.  The latest version of 23 (as of this answer) is 23.4.0.

Answer (score 1):

The best place to look as others mention is [Support Library Revision History](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html).

But there is another way. In your gradle define versions like this 23.+
it will automatically search and get the latest version in which the first version part is 23.

I should mention that i do not advise to use the second method because it may cause you automatically get the latest libraries ( Which are still in beta or alpha ) and it cause errors in your code.